# Access XML file as resource and load to datatable

Tags: c#, xml, resources, datatable

I am trying to store an XML file as a project resource so I do not have to hard code any file paths when I compile.  I keep on getting an error when I call ReadXML.  Any thoughts?  If there are better ways of referencing a file without hard coding a path please let me know.

Thanks!

```
public class XMLLoad
{

    public DataSet ds { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public string XLETable 
    {
        get
        {
            //Returns an XML file
            return Properties.Resources.mainXLETable;
        }
    }

    public XMLLoad(string xmlPrimaryKey)
    {
        this.PrimaryKey = xmlPrimaryKey;
    }

    public DataSet ReturnXMLFileAsDataSet(string dataTableName)
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(XLETable);

            var dt = new DataTable(dataTableName);
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not want to physically access xml file????

Comment: Yeah it would be OK if I could put in in the solution to physically access it.  My problem is that I do not want to break the file path references when I build and deploy the application.

Comment: if it in the solution it will always reference the same place what I do not understand is why you want to write it in a dataset

Comment: That is what I can't figure out.  For whatever reason when I hard codes the relative path to the xml file it can't locate it.  I have it at the root of my solution.

Comment: It should be just by using the mappath http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Create` method is expecting an URL not a string containing the XML data.

Try this:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XLETable));
```